# Обработка исключений С#

Tags: c#, исключения

```
try
{
x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
} catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{            
}
```

Каким образом можно обработать сразу два исключения? (`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` и `FormatException`)

Comment: В вашем случае лучше не доводить до исключения, а воспользоваться [Int32.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Просто добавьте ещё один блок `catch`:

```
try
{
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
{
    ...
}
catch (FormatException)
{
    ...
}
```

Если код обработки одинаковый, можно воспользоваться блоком `when` (C# 6.0+):

```
try
{
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (Exception e)
when (e is ArgumentOutOfRangeException
   || e is FormatException)
{
    ...
}
```

Ещё один вариант, аналогичный предыдущему, но работающий в версиях ниже C# 6.0:

```
try
{
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (!(e is ArgumentOutOfRangeException
       || e is FormatException))
        throw;
    ...
}
```